# Script 'cloud_12252494797.HitEffect.ServerScriptService.Follow the Tut and sub', Line 4

Tags: roblox

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qiBzm.jpg)
i got this error even if i don't have any script in my project, after i create new project it still says error
I searched many places but couldn't find anything,after running the project it appears,and before that i was experimenting with something related to effects and started getting that error and i couldn't fix it, so i stopped using that project and i created another project and it started appearing

Comment: It looks like you have a cloud plugin that's throwing the error.  Take a look at the [Managing Plugins section of this article](https://create.roblox.com/docs/studio/plugins#Manage%20Plugins) on how to disable them. Once it's disabled or uninstalled, you shouldn't see the error anymore.